# Regex using .match in javascript brings the result more than once

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this regex `\w?(row-)\d+` and I'm trying to get bits from the html using javascript
so this is a part of my html:

```
<div class="col-md-1"><input class="form-control row-25 all" type="text" value="NA" onchange="validate('rep',this)" disabled></div>
<div class="col-md-1"><input class="form-control row-25 all" type="text" value="$15" onchange="validate('rep',this)" disabled></div>
<div class="col-md-1"><input class="form-control row-25" type="text" value="Per number" disabled></div>
```

and that's my js `var rowIndex = element.className.match(/\w?(row-)\d+/);`

What i'm getting from that .match function is this

> row-25, row-

What I'm trying to get is only

> row-25

What am i doing wrong here? Thanks.

UPDATE:

Actually I have found an answer to how to get what I need but that doesn't explain the output still, what I did is I chose to read rowIndex[0], and neglect the rest, however why is "row-" appearing anyway?

Comment: You get `row-` because of the capturing group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `match()` returns either `null` or an array of results. These results are the full pattern (`\w?(row-)\d+`) as well as the subpatterns (`row-`) represented by the bits enclosed within parentheses. That said, as it stands, your regular expression will also match classes like `arrow-25` or `row-25xyz`. Here is a workaround if needed :

```
/(?:^|\s)(row-\d+)(?:\s|$)/
```

Dissection :

```
(...)       captures subpattern
(?:...)     doesn't capture subpattern
```

```
(?:^|\s)    the beginning of the string or a whitespace
(row-\d+)   "row-" plus at least one digit (subpattern 1)
(?:\s|$)    a whitespace or the end of the string
```

If you want to extract only the number :

```
/(?:^|\s)row-(\d+)(?:\s|$)/
```

Dissection :

```
(?:^|\s)   the beginning of the string or a whitespace
row-       "row-"
(\d+)      at least one digit (subpattern 1)
(?:\s|$)   a whitespace or the end of the string
```

Usage example :

```
var r = /(?:^|\s)row-(\d+)(?:\s|$)/,
    n = el.className.match(r);
if (n) { // if n is not null
    n = n[1]; // set n as subpattern 1
}
```

With a class name like `form-control row-25 all`, `n` will be `25`.

Also read :

- [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global%5fObjects/String/match)
- http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/redev2.shtml

Answer (score 0):

I you want to get `row-25` use:

```
rowIndex = element.className.match(/\w?(row-\d+)/);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your regex to:

```
/\w?row-\d+/
```

Since your regex has this capturing group `/(row-)/` therefore in the result you are getting 2 elements in the array:

1. Full matched input string
2. Captured group

Since you don't really need capturing group just don't put brackets around `row-`